How on opened form (BelongsToMany * BelongsToMany) to susbtitute standart select component with plugin?
In Laravel 10 / nova 4.27 app Category model has 'parent_id' field(root nodes)
and BelongsToMany profudct relationsL
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class Category extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    protected $table = 'categories';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $fillable
        = [
            'name', 'parent_id', 'slug', 'active',  'description'
        ];

    public function products(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }

Product model also has :
public function categories(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}

so in Product resource I added :
and see list of related categories with with "Attach category" button:

When I click on "Attach category" button - form for "category selection is opened:

I did not define this selection field.
As categories table has parent_id I need to select only categories.parent_id != null (not root elements)
Any Idea how can I do it?
I found https://github.com/creode-modules/nova-collapsible-radios plugin which seems good for thid task but
how can on this opened form to susbtitute standart select component with this plugin ?
Maybe some other decisions for my task?
